# How can I find gems & groups using Bundler in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I would like to load a Gemfile using the Bundler object in ruby and be able to view the gems, dependencies, and various groups.  Since this obviously isn't documented, does anyone with a knowledge of the bundler source know how to do this?

Comment: +1 because I've often wondered the same thing - how to inspect what bundler has decided the dependency graph for a set of gems is, (for example) to see exactly where a certain gem is getting included from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After poking around the Bundler source code... I found you can do this...

```
require 'bundler'
b = Bundler::Dsl.new
b.eval_gemfile('Gemfile')  # point to your Gemfile path

b.dependencies.each do |g|
  puts g.name
  puts g.groups
  puts g.requirements_list
end
```

@sevenseacat You might have to poke around a bit more to lookup other gems a particular gem is dependent on, but hopefully that gets you started.  It certainly accomplished what I was looking to do.

Comment: This only lists direct dependencies, not transitive dependencies. So it's not the full dependency graph.

Answer (score 1):

The only way, that I'm aware of, to get a representation of what groups hold what dependencies at which versions would be through `bundle viz`.

Via the [bundle viz documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.5/bundle_viz.html), or by `$ bundle help viz`, you can see that the `-V` option will output the versions in the graph generated.

Note, you'll need to install dependencies (typically `ruby-graphviz`). You'll get an image which looks something similar to:

[image: This example image from one of my discarded projects]

Note, this may not be the easiest way to parse this data; but, it is the available method.